# Admin Login With PassportJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, admin

Guys I can make user register and login. But I want to make a admin login. This admin will be a user too. So that I tried to make a `ensureAdmin function`. But it doesnt work. İt always redirects to login page.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password'
    },
      function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
          }
           bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
            }
          });
        });
      }
    ));

    function ensureAdmin(req, res, next){
      User.find({"username":"Alp"}
      ).exec(function(user){
      if(req.user = user){
        req.isAuthenticated()
        return next();
      } else {
        req.flash('danger', 'Please Login');
        res.redirect('/login');
      }
    });
    }
```

Can someone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Where did you call ensureAdmin?

Comment: In my add/article/ route.(GET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ensureAdmin` function I see an error in if statement.

```
if(req.user = user) ...
```

Other than that, you are complecating the flow.

`User.find({"username":"Alp"})` query would always return the user with username `Alp`. So, you can rewrite the function like this:

```
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next){
    if(req.user.username === 'Alp'){
        req.isAuthenticated()
        return next();
    } else {
        req.flash('danger', 'Please Login');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,

- Add a new field to user document as `isAdmin`
- Then, create a new middleware as `ensureAdmin`

```
const ensureAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user){
        return next(new Error("User Document not found."));
    }
    if (!req.user.isAdmin){
        return next(new Error("User not authorized to access this route."));
    }
    return next();
}
```

You can use it like this wherever needed:

```
app.post("/signin", passportLogin, ensureAdmin, controller.signin);
```

This will firstly check the user authentication from `passportLogin` and push the user document to this path `req.user`. So now our middleware `ensureAdmin` play the game. It will check the admin status `isAdmin`. If `isAdmin` is true it will push to our controller function otherwise throw it to error handlers.